# Injecting CSS to remove modals/popups from screenshot API (url2png.com)

Tags: javascript, css, web-scraping, screenshot

I am trying to build an application that will take in a CSV of urls and display screenshots of the webpages. However, I'm running into the problem that screenshots return with a full page modal/popup that blocks site content. The API I am using ([url2png.com](https://www.url2png.com/)) allows for CSS injection or a user agent parameter. I have tried to use inject a CSS file like this, but it hasn't functioned properly.

```
.ju_overlay {
    display: none;
}

#modalcontent {
    display: none;
}

.shopify-section-popup-subscription {
    display: none;
}

.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
```

Does anyone know an effective way of removing the modals/preventing them from loading?

Comment: Do you know exactly that these classes are the only ones applicable to the modals that pop up?

Comment: @Siavas, thanks for the quick response. I am testing it right now on just 2 urls that have these classes. When I replace display: block with display: none in web inspectors, the modals disappear correctly. I am not sure what is getting lost in translation when the CSS file is getting injected.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification too! So then you are using `&custom_css_url=http://url2png.com/tests/css/test.css` as per docs? If so what is the link you provide to it?

Comment: http://lucasxsong.com/inject.css This is the sheet that I have loaded. I have tried to use a download link to a css hosted on Google Drive, but to no avail.

Comment: It may be from the order of the CSS loaded. Could you try setting !important to all of your rules and see if it works that way?

Comment: That just worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that, you're very welcome. I have added this solution as an answer so other people can see it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found in our conversation it seems url2png is either appending your CSS before the site's ones (and has therefore lower priority), or the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your rulesets do not have as high priority as the site's CSS. Although using `!important` is a generally a bad practice, in web scraping and especially in your case of intending to force these rules, it would be the best approach to take.

So just change the declarations to include `!important` and it should be good to go:

```
.ju_overlay {
    display: none !important;
}

#modalcontent {
    display: none !important;
}

.shopify-section-popup-subscription {
    display: none !important;
}

.modal-backdrop {
    display: none !important;
}
```